# Lightbox does not fade out css dropdown menu and sagscroller when image is opened

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins

I use an [css dropdown](http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/dropdown.simple.horizontal.html) menu and an Automatic scroller ([sagscroller](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/sagscroller.htm))
Both of these will not fade out when I click the image of my lightbox2 gallery

First I had the problem that the image appeared behind my menu and nothing faded. I tackled that problem with setting the z-index to 1000 (was 100):

```
#lightbox{  
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 1000; 
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 0;
}
```

But now the next problem arised....both dropdown menu and sagscroller didnt fade when an image of the lightbox gallery was clicked.
I spend all yesterday and part of today searching for an answer on the net.
Tried some things I found like placing:

```
#overlay { width: 100%;
height:1000px !important; }
```

in the css. But to no effect.

I found a sollution that I might need to change library's from deliscious to jquery so I downloaded a new version of lightbox and used that....no change.

I found a solution on this page. To change the z-index to 5000

```
#lightbox {
    left:0;
    line-height:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5000; /* move the lightbox above all other elements */
}
```

Still no change.
Everything works great! Menu, sagscroller and lightbox....only the fading of the other things doesn't happen.
Could someone please help me with this? 
I'm open to all sollutions. I only hope they do not ask me to change my menu tho...
But if everything else fails....

Thanks a million!

PS: I use lightbox2 but couldnt post more than 2 links cause I am a new user

Answer (score 0):

You also have to raise the z-index of the overlay.

```
#overlay { z-index:9998; }
#lightbox { z-index:9999; }
```

The overlay is the layer that make the other elements fade. This overlay has to have a higher z-index then the other ones. But to have the lightbox on top of that overlay, it has to have an even higher z-index than the overlay.

Comment: Thank you very much!
After posting here I fidled around with that overlay and your right (ofcourse)! I was posting my own answer when I saw there already was an answer (yours). Thanks for your fast answering tho!